# Как ускорить вычисление оптического потока алгоритмом Лукаса-Канаде?

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv-faq

В OpenCV имеется реализация алгоритма Лукаса-Канаде с использованием пирамид изображений. Работает относительно быстро и, в целом, скоростью своей обязана тому, что вычисляет оптический поток не между всеми пикселями предыдущего и следующего кадров, а исключительно в отношении точек интереса. Но если последних оказывается слишком много, то скорость может быть и снижена, причём довольно существенно.

Имеется ли возможность увеличить производительность, не ограничивая количество точек интереса?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для вычисления оптического потока алгоритмом Лукаса-Канаде с использованием пирамиды изображений используется функция:

```
void calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(
    InputArray prevImg,
    InputArray nextImg,
    InputArray prevPts,
    InputOutputArray nextPts,
    OutputArray status,
    OutputArray err,
    Size winSize = Size(21,21),
    int maxLevel = 3,
    TermCriteriacriteria = TermCriteria(TermCriteria::COUNT + TermCriteria::EPS, 30, 0.01),
    int flags = 0,
    double minEigThreshold = 1e-4)
```

Но интерес при решении задачи ускорения представляют лишь два её первых аргумента, в качестве которых традиционно подаются матрицы исходных изображений. Проблема заключается в том, что при каждом вызове `calcOpticalFlowPyrLK()`, последняя "молча" выполнит построение пирамид изображений для каждого из кадров: `предыдущего` и `следующего`.

Получается, что на каждой межкадровой итерации вызова алгоритма, когда т.н. `следующий` кадр уже будет отмечен как `предыдущий`, а его место в качестве `следующего` займёт новый кадр, случится очевидный перерасход ресурсов. Оно и понятно, для вновь `предыдущего` кадра пирамида изображений уже вычислялась, была использована, но не была сохранена. В итоге, для каждой последующей межкадровой итерации производится повторное построение пирамиды изображений для одного из кадров в кадровой последовательности.

Непосредственно построением пирамиды изображений для последующего её использования в вычислении оптического потока занимается функция `buildOpticalFlowPyramid()`. Именно её прозрачно и вызывает `calcOpticalFlowPyrLK()` для каждого из кадров. Тем не менее, результат работы `buildOpticalFlowPyramid()`, как это недвусмысленно указано в справке, может быть задействован в `calcOpticalFlowPyrLK()` как поданый на вход извне вместо обычных изображений.

Рассмотрим два примера использования `calcOpticalFlowPyrLK()`.

Традиционный:

```
cv::Mat prv_mat, nxt_mat;

while(true) {
    if(prv_mat.empty()) {
        prv_mat = readNewFrame();
        if(prv_mat.empty()) break;

        continue;
    }

    nxt_mat = readNewFrame();
    if(nxt_mat.empty()) break;

    // Вычисляем оптический поток.
    cv::calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(prv_mat, nxt_mat, ...);

    // Используем его.
    ...

    // Меняем матрицы местами, чтобы текущий "следующий" кадр
    // стал в новой итерации "предыдущим".
    std::swap(prv_mat, nxt_mat);
}
```

При использовании данного подхода на каждой итерации в `while(true) {...}` создание пирамиды изображений будет производиться для каждого кадра, т.е. два раза.

Подход с использованием внешнего вызова `buildOpticalFlowPyramid()`:

```
std::vector<cv::Mat> prv_pyr, nxt_pyr;

while(true) {
    if(prv_pyr.empty()) {
        cv::Mat mat = readNewFrame();
        if(mat.empty()) break;

        // Строим пирамиду изображений для кадра.
        cv::buildOpticalFlowPyramid(mat, prv_pyr, ...);

        continue;
    }

    cv::Mat mat = readNewFrame();
    if(mat.empty()) break;

    // Строим пирамиду изображений для нового кадра.
    cv::buildOpticalFlowPyramid(mat, nxt_pyr, ...);

    // Вычисляем оптический поток.
    cv::calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(prv_pyr, nxt_pyr, ...);

    // Используем его.
    ...

    // Меняем вектора местами, чтобы текущая "следующая" пирамида
    // стала в новой итерации "предыдущей".
    std::swap(prv_pyr, nxt_pyr);
}
```

При использовании данного подхода на каждой итерации в `while(true) {...}` создание пирамиды изображений будет производиться только для одного кадра, т.е. один раз. Скорость работы алгоритма может увеличиться в отдельных случаях в два раза.